# Cannot convert HashMap data to List of objects (Model class)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, hashmap

I have list of addresses in the Firebase Database. It is retrieved like this:

```
    addressesRef
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {

                    
                    //Toast.makeText(this@AddressActivity, "Addresses fetched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

Notice the the addresses with 2 IDs (they got fetched in reverse order)

[image]

I am trying to convert this into an `ArrayList<Address>` where Address is my model class. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you need the value of a single child (Ad_100000) or of all children (Ad_100000, Ad_100001 etc)?

Comment: All of the children, hence the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you have in the database is a `Map<String, Address>` and not a `List<Address>`. If you want to get just the `Address` value, you can either load the map and just get its value, or (preferred):

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        for (addressSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            val address = addressSnapshot.getValue<Address>();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where were you Sir?! I had to waste so many hours for this. Thank you!